How can I receive TCP messages using Azure Functions or Logic Apps?
I'm looking to receive TCP messages using Azure Functions or Logic Apps. I understand that both services are typically triggered by HTTP requests, but I'm wondering if there's a way to run a TCP receiver app within an Azure Function to accept TCP messages. Additionally, I haven't found any networking settings in Azure Functions that allow TCP traffic. Is there a workaround or a configuration option to enable TCP support in Azure Functions or Logic Apps?
I tried using an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger, hoping to find a way to bind it to TCP instead. I expected to configure the function to listen for TCP messages, but couldn't find any settings or options for enabling TCP support. Instead, the function remained limited to HTTP requests, and I didn't receive any TCP messages.

There is no such thing as a "TCP message". TCP is an unstructured bidirectional byte stream. Any message, request etc semantic is defined in the application protocol on top of TCP, for example in HTTP. So if you want to have something triggered on a message you would have to specify the application protocol first which has defined what a message is and then can look for a trigger for this specific application protocol, not generic TCP.

Actually, I want to receive HL7 messages in an Azure Function and Logic App. Here's my current code for the Azure Function:
My end goal is to receive these messages in both Azure Functions and Logic Apps. I think Azure Functions may not allow TCP requests due to restrictions, but if I'm mistaken, please help me achieve this setup. Thanks!

I understand that you want to receive HL7 messages. HL7 messages generally use  MLLP protocol which is built on top of TCP/IP.
Azure functions don't support TCP triggers. You may want to use Azure Relay which supports hybrid connections(HTTP and TCP) to listen for incoming HL7 messages and use Azure functions to process the HL7 messages.
You can also containerize your application using an Azure container instance to listen for HL7 messages using a custom port and TCP protocol.
